# SparkContext has been shutdown

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I have a Spark job which looks like

```
def run():
    spark_session = helper_class.create_spark_session()
    // do some logic
    spark_session.stop()
```

now I want to write some integration tests for the job and get 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown`
in two cases

1. I have two test cases that run the same job but with different test data, first test case runs ok but the second one fails with the above error
2. Even if my first test case runs ok I want to assert the job results (stored in local test location), so to achieve that I want to create a spark session, read the files and then compare the data frames but get the same error

Is there a way how I can force Spark to create a new context or how I can deal with this issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't shutdown spark context in your run function. Define for that another function, i.e. stop. In your real execution call run and the stop functions.
In your tests execute shutdown spark context after all tests.